# Respond to remote form_for with html or json?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, activerecord

I've currently got several partials that contain forms for different AR models. I'm using these to build a dashboard-style pages so I can do an ajax post to CRUD controllers (rather than posting to a bunch of different actions within a dashboard controller).

Since I'm using AR to validate the data, I'd like to be able to just render the correct partial with the correct object in the CRUD controller and use that as my response. Something like this:

```
if @note.save?
  flash[:notice] = "Note successfully saved!"
  render '_note_form', :layout => false
else
  flash[:notice] = "Something went wrong. Note was not saved!"
  flash[:error] = @note.errors.full_messages.to_sentence
  render '_note_form', :layout => false
end
```

Then I'm adding a js function to handle that response by replacing the form with the response like so:

```
$(function() {
    $('form#new_note_form').bind('ajax:success', function(evt, data, status, xhr){
        $("#new_note_form").replaceWith(xhr.responseText);
    });
});
```

This gives me validation the same type of validation that I would see if I did a standard post, but only refreshes the partial rather than the entire page.

I can't help but to feel like there is a better way to handle this. Should I just be passing the error/success messages via json and handling them appropriately on the front-end? Is it bad practice to just replace the entire form?

Comment: I prefer to use json and an MV* JavaScript framework like Backbone or Angular.

Comment: I would say that unless you want to learn the Javascript frameworks as cortex mentions above that you are doing it one of a few correct ways. And quite frankly the way you did it requires less coding than the Javascript MV framework way.